# Complex Mean Value Theorem: Counterexamples

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

*This thread is just to collect some examples...*

Given an open domain $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$.

Consider a holomorphic function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$.

What would be a counterexample to:
$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)\quad(c\in\Omega)$$
and when does even the estimate fail:
$$|f(b)-f(a)|\leq\|f'\|_\infty|b-a|$$

*Feel free to post anything related you have in mind!*

Comment: I imagine you mean $|f(b)-f(a)|\leq ||{f'}||_\infty(b-a)$.

Comment: I guess you mean the missing modulus on the RHS? Corrected. Thanks!  ;)

Comment: No but that is also true :) I meant the inequality sign.

Comment: Aaah ok got it, thanks again. ;)

Comment: Math.SE is not the suitable place for "collecting examples".

Comment: @mrf: I understand, then let me close this thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exponential function $f(x)=e^x$. 
$$
f(2\pi i)-f(0) = 0
$$
but $f'(c)\cdot 2\pi i=e^c\cdot  2\pi i$ can never be zero. For the estimate I don't know yet.

Answer (score 2):

The estimate is always true, **as long as $\Omega$ is convex**.

Because in this case,

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(b) - f(a) &=& \int_0^1 (\frac{d}{dt}f(a + t(b-a))) \, dt\\
& = &\int_0^1 f'(a + t(b-a)) \cdot (b-a) \, dt.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now simply take the absolute value and use that: $|\int f \, dt| \leq \int |f|\,dt$

Hence, this has not so much to do with $f$ assuming complex values than with the shape of $\Omega \subset \Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**

I will give only a sketch!!

**Reference**

This example is taken from: [MVT: Logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208628/79762)

**Counterexample**

Given the cutted unit circle: $\Omega:=\mathbb{S}\setminus\{-1\}$

Consider the main branch of the logarithm: $\ln(re^{i\varphi}):=\ln r+i\varphi$

Assuming the estimate holds:
$$\Delta\downarrow0:\quad2\pi\leftarrow|2\pi-2\Delta|=\left|\ln e^{i(\pi-\Delta)}-\ln e^{i(-\pi+\Delta)}\right|\\\leq\sup_{z\in\Omega}\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|\cdot\left|e^{i(\pi+\Delta)}-e^{i(\pi-\Delta)}\right|=\left|e^{i2\Delta}-1\right|\to 0$$
But that is a contradiction!